# GitLab CI including a project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

So I have many many small projects on gitlab, all use the same CI script to build. To make entire system cleaner I put the CI script in its own project and the small projects CI script just pull the script from the central project i.e.

```
stages:
  - build

include:
  - project: 'Company/CI-Templates'
    file: '/Swift-Apple/Swift_Apple_Build.yml'
```

With the central script being like

```
stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - git submodule sync --recursive
  - git submodule update --init --recursive

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
  - xcodebuild archive -scheme "$AppName" -archivePath "build/App.xcarchive"
  - xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "build/App.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/" -exportOptionsPlist "ExportOptions.plist"  
  - appcenter login --token $AppCenterToken
  - appcenter distribute release -f "$IPAPath" -g Collaborators -r "$Reason" --app $AppCenterPath
```

Now this runs as expected, the central script when called runs local in the project. The issue I have is "ExportOptions.plist" is a separate file that ideally id like to be in the central CI location, but as the script runs local when called, im unsure what file path to put in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you download "ExportOptions.plist" from your central CI project with `curl`?  Then you can load it locally.